# Mediation analysis: When does the total effect exactly equal direct effect + indirect effect?

Tags: mediation

Typically in mediation analyses we see diagrams like the following, in which `X` is the *causal variable*, `Y` is the *outcome variable*, and `M` is the *mediating variable*. Meanwhile path `c` is called the *total effect*, path `c'` is called the *direct effect*, and path `ab` is called the *indirect effect*.

[image: Mediation]

The equation `c = c' + ab` is often mentioned. When does it exactly hold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David Kenny writes [on his website](http://davidakenny.net/cm/mediate.htm) that:

> The equation of `c = c' + ab` exactly holds when a) multiple regression
>   (or structural equation modeling without latent variables) is used, b)
>   the same cases are used in all the analyses, c) and the same
>   covariates are in all the equations.  However, the two are only
>   approximately equal for multilevel models, logistic analysis and
>   structural equation modeling with latent variables.

I'll welcome, and will accept, an answer that improves on this explanation, e.g. by discussing why these conditions are necessary for `c'+ab` to exactly equal `c`, and why they're only approximately equal for multilevel models, logistic analysis and structural equation modeling with latent variables.